# Python functions and formatting not working

Tags: python

I'm currently having a problem with a function in python. This is my code before I tried putting it in a function:

```
for i in range(4):
    for y in Days:
      for x in "ABCDEF":
        data = input("What was the punctuality for bus " + x + " on " + str(y) + ", Week " + str(Week) + "? ")
        Bus = "Bus" + str(x)
        Buses[Bus].append(str(data))
        print()
    Week += 1
```

And it works like it is meant to, however I tried putting it in a function:

```
def InputData():
  for i in range(4):
    for y in Days:
      for x in "ABCDEF":
        data = input("What was the punctuality for bus " + x + " on " + str(y) + ", Week " + str(Week) + "? ")
        Bus = "Bus" + str(x)
        Buses[Bus].append(str(data))
        print()
    Week += 1
```

And I am getting errors about the whole Week += 1 part. They say:

```
[pyflakes] local variable 'Week' (defined in enclosing scope on line 11) 
referenced before assignment
[pyflakes] local variable 'Week' is assigned to but never used
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Week += 1` that doesn't initialize to 0 automatically. Do it manually at start or use `global`

Comment: You initialized `Week` somewhere earlier in your first code. There is no initialization of a local variable `Week` in your function.

Comment: ro try `Week = Week + 1` but that's quite a hack

Comment: This isn't the cause of your issue, but I noticed you're not following the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Style Guide. I'd recommend doing so in the future. Specifically, your variable and function names should be in `snake_case`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Week = 0
```

Put this at the beginning of your code.